# Ionic Native Diagnostic Plugin - plugin_not_installed

Tags: cordova, ionic2, ionic-native

I am using the Ionic Native plugin Diagnostic according to the [website](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/diagnostic/) but for some reason, when I test it out on my Android device using the Ionic View app, I always get plugin_not_installed.

I have tried so many things online but nothing is working. I have updated my ionic version, cordova version, npm, everything. Can I not test it using the Ionic View plugin?

Any idea why it may not be working for me?

Ionic Version: 3.15.2
Cordova Version: 7.0.1

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the [supported plugins](https://docs.ionic.io/tools/view/#supported-plugins) of ionic view you will see that only a specific list of plugins is supported and the diagnostic plugin is one of them. You will have to test your app in the emulator or on the device using:

```
ionic cordova run android/ios --device/--simulator
```

Comment: Thanks David but I was under the impression that testing it with Ionic View app is the same as testing it on a real device. Shouldn't it give me the same result or does the Diagnostic plugin not work when testing on the Ionic View app, even though other plugins like LocationAccuracy works just fine?

Comment: No it is by far not the same, the ionic view app just "loads" the code you have in your `www` folder into its webview, so everything thats not in there (like cordova plugins) will not be available. They included a few popular plugins in the ionic view app so they are available unfortunatly for you the diagnostics plugin is not available.

Comment: wow thanks a bunch David. You've been so helpful. I wasted 2 days trying to figure out why this is not working. I'll try your approach above.

Comment: No problem at all, glad I could help you out! If my answer solved your problem please be so kind and accept it so this question is marked as solved :-)